# Exporting ipa in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store-connect, ipa

I have a project on Xcode, and i have set its deployment target to iphone only, but recently while uploading on app store, it got rejected as it found to have iPad support. I have set its deployment to iphone only in general target settings. And now keeping the settings same, I ran it on ipad simulator and its running there. What could be the possible reason behind this? Do I need to change settings somewhere else also to restrict it to iPhone only?

P.S. 
1) This project of mine is linked with react-native, if it has something to do with it
2) I have upgraded to xcode 9 gem seed(iOS 11.0), in case its required to mention here, although the app version got rejected when it was built and from previous xcode version.

Comment: Non universal iPhone apps run on iPad with a 1x/2x emulator mode : [reference](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/45511). So, its unlikely that, this is a reason for app rejection. Can you provide more details about the exact reason for rejection?

Answer (score 0):

Select Your Target and Than choose iPhone in Development Info for new build upload with incremented build number.
 [image]

Comment: Done, its behaving the same way!

Comment: Clean your project and build

Comment: In build setting you can check `Targeted Device Family`